# Getting "The following has evaluated to null or missing" from freemaker in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, freemarker

I have the following pom.xml file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.chat</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>app</name>
    <description>A chat application written in spring boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-boot-admin.version>3.0.0-M4</spring-boot-admin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.reporter2</groupId>
            <artifactId>zipkin-reporter-brave</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-admin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-docs</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <backend>html</backend>
                            <doctype>book</doctype>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-asciidoctor</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-restdocs.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have the following controller class.

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class Controllers {

    @GetMapping("/signup")
    public String getSignUpPage(@RequestParam String name, @ModelAttribute ModelMap modelMap) {
        System.out.println("Name is: " + name);
        modelMap.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "signup";
    }

}
```

I have the following freemaker template file.

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello, ${name}</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

When i am visiting http://localhost:8080/signup?name=rahul , then i am getting the following error.

```java
Hello, FreeMarker template error (DEBUG mode; use RETHROW in production!): The following has evaluated to null or missing: ==> name [in template "signup.ftlh" at line 6, column 22] ---- Tip: If the failing expression is known to legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)?? ---- ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related): - Failed at: ${name} [in template "signup.ftlh" at line 6, column 20] ---- Java stack trace (for programmers): ---- freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...] at freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException.getInstance(InvalidReferenceException.java:134) at freemarker.core.EvalUtil.coerceModelToTextualCommon(EvalUtil.java:481) at freemarker.core.EvalUtil.coerceModelToStringOrMarkup(EvalUtil.java:401) at freemarker.core.EvalUtil.coerceModelToStringOrMarkup(EvalUtil.java:370) at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.calculateInterpolatedStringOrMarkup(DollarVariable.java:104) at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:63) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:335) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:341) at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:314) at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:383) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.processTemplate(FreeMarkerView.java:329) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.doRender(FreeMarkerView.java:264) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.renderMergedTemplateModel(FreeMarkerView.java:215) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractTemplateView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractTemplateView.java:179) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:314) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1414) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1158) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1097) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:705) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Why this issue is coming?

My directory structure
[image]

Comment: What does the `System.out.println("Name is: " + name)` print? Maybe `name` is `null`?

Comment: In case the name is null, then the controller method won’t be mapped. Because `@ RequestParam` marks the attributes as required by default.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like that freemarker 2.3.32 does not work using spring boot 3.
For example, the following code works fine with spring boot 2.6.7, freemarker 2.3.31, but does not work work spring boot 3.0.4

```
    <h1>Hello, ${RequestParameters.name}</h1>
```

You will get the exception like:

```
Hello, FreeMarker template error (DEBUG mode; use RETHROW in production!): The following has evaluated to null or missing: ==> RequestParameters [in template "main.ftl" at line 24, column 18] ---- Tip: If the failing expression is known to legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)?? ---- ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related): - Failed at: ${RequestParameters.name} [in template "main.ftl" at line 24, column 16] ---- Java stack trace (for programmers): ----
```

I think Freemarker still uses the old java ee packages like javax.servlet instead jakarta.servlet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRmLz.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgQVG.png)

Comment: I think you're right. I have raised an issue in the spring framework github, here's the link https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/30186
If people with the same issue comment on it maybe they'll prioritise at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be using @ModelAttribute there. Try this:

```
@GetMapping("/signup")
public String getSignUpPage(@RequestParam String name, Model model) {
```

I also changed ModelMap to org.springframework.ui.Model as a more generic approach.

---

According to https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_misc_servlet.html Freemarker also automatically puts request parameters into `RequestParameters` hash variable. So you should not even need to put params into Model yourself and this freemarker code should be sufficient:

`<h1>Hello, ${RequestParameters.name}</h1>`

Comment: It's better practice for the View to only rely on the the Model though, and leave dealing with request parameters to the Controller method.

Answer (score 0):

yes, @Ilya correctly mentioned the [Freemarker docs](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_misc_servlet.html) which state that there used to exist a fourth hash named `RequestParameters`.
And the minimalistic change to make it work, would be to change to `org.springframework.ui.Model`

And @Damir is also correct: **Spring Boot 3+** (and consequently Spring Framework 6+) **breaks Freemarker**. Check @Neets comment on his answer. I suspect they won't be introducing a fix (soon).

And here's the workaround where you fetch the param from the URI if you don't want to use `@RequestParam`:

```
    @GetMapping("/signup")
    public String signupEndpoint(HttpServletRequest servletRequest, Model model) {
        // relating to your question, you'd substitute "parameterName" in this method by "name"
        String urlParam = servletRequest.getParameter("parameterName");

        // make sure that the param isn't null. Freemarker will always throw an error
        if (null == urlParam) {
            urlParam = "urlParam was empty!";
        }

        // provided you called http://localhost:8080/signup?name=rahul 
        // the variable urlParam would be initialized with value "rahul"
        // Spring will use the Model to populate your html
        model.addAttribute("parameterName", urlParam);
        return "signup";
    }
```